# Killing form for Lie algebras vs trace map for field extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, lie-algebras, trace, bilinear-form

I'm currently studying Lie algebras and i ran into the Killing form, defined for a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a field $k$ by:  $\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow k, (x,y) \mapsto tr(ad(x)ad(y))$ . This map is useful because if $k$ is algebraically closed and its characteristic is zero, the Killing form is non degenerate iff $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple.

On the other hand, given a field extension of finite degree $K/k$, one defines the trace map $K \rightarrow k$ which sends $x\in K$ to $tr(r_x)$, where $r_x \in End_k(K)$ is the multiplication by $x$. Now, $K/k$ is separable iff the bilinear symmetric form $K \times K \rightarrow k, (x,y) \mapsto tr(r_xr_y)$ is non degenerate.

My question is: is there a reason why these two definitions look the same and give such similar results?

**Edit.** Maybe one way to proceed could be to search a Lie algebra whose Killing form is related to the trace map of $K/k$.
The map $r : K \rightarrow End_k(K), x \mapsto r_x$ sends $K$ into $GL(n,k)$, so one may consider the Zariski closure of the image $r(K)$; this will be an algebraic group with an associated Lie algebra. Now, everything is constructed from $K/k$, so I'd expect some relations. Could this be the case?

Comment: This is definitely a general theme, I would love to know a good answer. Another instance of this is finite dimensional algebras over $k$, they are semisimple iff this form is nondegenerate.

Comment: I asked a mildly related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388089/96384 My suspicion is that there is a far more abstract framework that singles out certain scalar-valued linear or multilinear maps on certain algebras which are invariant under certain morphisms. (Probably one should take a more Grothendieckian viewpoint and define them not on individual algebras, but on categories of algebras, and subject them to some compatibility conditions.) Those "forms" (generalizing trace, Killing and possibly others) then carry significant information about their domain's structure.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg this looks like a very ambitious goal; does there exist anything in literature that goes in this direction?

Comment: Not as far as I know. But I'd be happy to learn.